# Problema con variables de sesión

Tags: php, mvc, poo

```
    <?php session_start(); if($_SESSION['usuario']){
     header('Location:http://localhost:7777/TM/view/login/Administrador.php');
     }
     require_once 'model/database.php';
```

---

```
 $controller = 'login'; //llamammos al controlador
 
 // Todo esta lógica hara el papel de un FrontController
     if(!isset($_REQUEST['il'])) {
     require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";//instanciamos al controlador
     $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
     $controller = new $controller;
     $controller->Login_Vista();
 
 
 
 } else {
     // Obtenemos el controlador que queremos cargar
     $controller = strtolower($_REQUEST['il']);
     $accion = isset($_REQUEST['a']) ? $_REQUEST['a'] : 'Login';
```

---

```
 // Instanciamos el controlador
 require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";
 $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
 $controller = new $controller;
```

---

```
 // Llama la accion
 call_user_func(array($controller, $accion)); }
```

[image: Ver imagen correspondiente]

---

### //controlador

```
 <?php require_once 'model/login.php';
 
 
 class loginController {
 
     private $model;
 
     public function __CONSTRUCT()
     {
         $this->model = new login();
     }
 
     public function Login_Vista()
     {
         require_once 'view/login/header.php';
         require_once 'view/login/login.php';
         
 
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
             $email=$_POST['email'];
             $password=$_POST['password'];
             $tipo_usuario=$_POST['tipo_usuario'];
 
             if(empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($tipo_usuario)){
                 echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Nombre de usuario o contraseña vacio</div>';
             }else{
                 $user = new login();
 
                 if($user->getUser($email,$password,$tipo_usuario)){
                     session_start();
                     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $email;
                     header('Location: /view/login/Administrador.php');
                 }else{
                     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Usuario no existe</div>';
                 }
             }
 
         }
 
     }
 
 
 }
```

---

```
//modelo <?php class login {
 
     private $pdo;
     public $id;
     public $email;
     public $password;
     public $tipo_usuario;
 
     public function __CONSTRUCT()
     {
     try
     {
         $this->pdo = Database::StartUp();
     }
     catch(Exception $e)
     {
         die($e->getMessage());
     } }
 
     /*public function getUser($email, $password, $tipo_usuario){
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password' AND tipo_usuario = '$tipo_usuario' ";
         $result = $this->StartUp()->query($sql);
         $numRows = $result->num_rows;
         if($numRows == 3){
             return true;
         }
 
         return false;
     }*/
   
 
     public function getUser($email, $password, $tipo_usuario)
     {
         try
         {
             $result = array();
 
             $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password' AND tipo_usuario =
 '$tipo_usuario'");
             $stm->execute();
 
             return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         }
         catch(Exception $e)
         {
             die($e->getMessage());
         }
     }
 
 
 }
```

---

```
//vista
 
 <?php session_start(); if($_SESSION['usuario']){
     header('Location: view/login/Administrador.php'); } ?> <div class="container border col-sm-4 lg-4">
     <br>
     <form action="" method="post">
         <div class="form-group row align-content-center">
             <label for="correo" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Correo:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-8 sm-6">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="password" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-key fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Ingrese
 Contraseña:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-8 sm-6">
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
             </div>
               </div>
                 <!--<div class="align-content-center">
                     <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="tipo_usuario" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Seleccione un tipo
 de Usuario:</label>
                         <div class="col-lg-8 sm-6">
                             <select name="tipo_usuario" class="form-control">
                                 <option selected>Por Favor Elija su usuario adecuado</option>
                                 <option>Administrador</option>
                                 <option>Usuario</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>-->
                 <div class="form-group row align-content-center">
             <label for="correo" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Tipo
 Uusario:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-8 sm-6">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario" required autocomplete="off">
             </div>
         </div>
                 <div class="align-content-center">
               <div class="form-group row">
                 <div class="col-lg-6 sm-6">
                     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                 </div> 
               </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
              </div>  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   </body> </html>
```

[image: Error mencionado]

Comment: Añade el código y error como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Gracias por comentar y ayudar a este novato, ya agregue el codigo.

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba que la sesión no esté creada previamente

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre_de_tu_variable_de_session'])){
    session_start();
}
```